# End behavior limit function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am currently studying what happens when we evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}$ for different functions $f(x)$. For the sake of being concise, I will write $L(f) = \lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}$.

Currently, I have shown that for any polynomial $f(x)$ we have:

$$L(f) = 1 \text{ if } f \text{ has even degree}$$

$$L(f) = -1 \text{ if } f \text{ has odd degree.}$$

Let $p(x) = \Sigma_{n=0}^{k} a_n x^n$ be a polynomial and let $N = $max{n : $a_{2n+1} \ne 0$}. If $f(x) = e^{p(x)}$, then:

$$L(f) = \infty \text{ when } a_{2N+1} >0,$$

$$L(f) = 0 \text{ when } a_{2N+1} < 0$$

$$L(f) = 1 \text{ when } p(x) \text{ is only even powers of x.}$$

Does $L(f)$ have any uses? What are some other functions to try for $f(x)$ that might yield interesting results? I am sure there are some quick results if we broaden $f$ to being an even/odd function.

Comment: I don't think your claim about even/odd functions is true. Consider f(x) = 0. This is both even and odd, but L(f) is undefined

Comment: Is there another counter example besides the zero function? Perhaps my claim could be modified.